# Erro de certificado SSL ao utilizar pip install no raspberry

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi, pip

Estou tentando instalar a biblioteca opencv para utilizá-lo em um projeto num dispositivo raspberry com raspbian e quando utilizo o comando pip recebo o seguinte erro:

```
(venv) pi@raspberrypi:~/teste $ pip install opencv-python
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Collecting opencv-python
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate is not yet valid (_ssl.c:1056)'))': /simple/opencv-python/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate is not yet valid (_ssl.c:1056)'))': /simple/opencv-python/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate is not yet valid (_ssl.c:1056)'))': /simple/opencv-python/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate is not yet valid (_ssl.c:1056)'))': /simple/opencv-python/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate is not yet valid (_ssl.c:1056)'))': /simple/opencv-python/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv-python (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for opencv-python
```

Depois de realizar algumas pesquisas percebi que o erro pode ser causado pela data e hora incorreta no dispositivo, como não tenho domínio na utilização do raspbian, ajuda para acertar data e hora serão bem vindas. Caso esse seja uma possível solução.

Answer (score 0):

O link utilizado pelo pip https://www.piwheels.org/simple parece ser recente (utilizado em 17/04/2020) e o certificado de segurança utilizado por ele parece ainda não ser reconhecido com confiável. Para burlar essa verificação de segurança basta fazer como no exemplo:

`pip install picamera --trusted-host www.piwheels.org`